# loop in checked value angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, checkbox

i need to send every employee i checked to postCouncilAbsence function parameter, i want to make a loop to loop each employee i checked then send him as parameter .. any help using typescript?

---

component.ts:

```
onattendanceSave(form:NgForm){
    this.index = this.attendanceForm.value
    console.log(this.index);
    Object.keys(this.index).forEach( key => {
    this.dataStorageService.postCouncilAbsence(this.index,this.Id)
    .subscribe(
        response => {
            console.log('save'+ this.index);
        }),
        error =>{ 
            console.log('error');
        }
  });
}
onChange(attendance:string, isChecked: boolean) {
    const attendanceFormArray = 
    <FormArray>this.attendanceForm.controls.isAttend;
    if(isChecked) {
        attendanceFormArray.push(new FormControl(attendance));
    } else {
      let index = attendanceFormArray.controls.findIndex(x => x.value == attendance)
      attendanceFormArray.removeAt(index);
    }
}
```

component.html:

```
<form [formGroup]="attendanceForm" >
 <div class="row">
    <table class="table table-hover table-condensed text-center table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
               <th> attendances </th>
               <th> check </th>
             </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let attendance of attendances"  >
             <td hidden>{{attendance.Employee_ID}}</td>
             <td > {{attendance.Emp_Name}} </td>
              <td> 
                <div class="form-check">
                    <label class="form-check-label">
                      <input type="checkbox (change)="onChange(attendance.Employee_ID,$event.target.checked)" >                                                                              {{attendance.isAttend}}
                    </label>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
     </table>
   </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" (click)="onattendanceSave(attendanceForm.value)"> save </button>
  </div>
  </form>
```

i want to send ID of each employee to this function :

```
postCouncilAbsence(absence, userId){
    let url = 'http://api.azharcouncil.com/api/CouncilAbsences/PostCouncilAbsence?Council_Id='+13+'&Emp_Id='+absence+'&User_Id='+userId;
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }); 
    return this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(absence), options);
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling `onattendanceSave()`?

Comment: sorry, i edited my question

Comment: Why not create a variable in your `*.ts` file to manipulate during your call to `onChange()` and then use that when you call `postCouncilAbsence()`?

Comment: i don't understand ! :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are already sending the ID back when you call `onChange()`. You could capture it then in a variable and then use it on when you call `postCouncilAbsence()`

component.ts

```
employeeId: string;

onChange(attendance:string, isChecked: boolean) {
  //your code
  this.employeeId = attendance;
}

postCouncilAbsence(absence, userId){
  const employeeId = this.employeeId; // don't need this but it's here to show you
  //your code and you can use this.employeeId
}
```